# Unable to remove phonegap plugin via command line

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-cli

I am trying to remove this ["background audio" cordova/phonegap plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-backgroundaudio/tree/31ab23878fcd4b3b26b44abc11719f3f21794594) from my project by using the below command, but it is failing for some reason.

```
$ sudo phonegap plugin remove "nl.x-services.plugins.backgroundaudio"

Uninstalling nl.x-services.plugins.backgroundaudio from ios

Error: Cannot read property 'buffer' of undefined
```

I am using Phonegap CLI 6.0.1 (cordova build version 4.0.1) testing on iOS8/9. Please let me know if i am missing something.

Comment: I tried this command and works like a charm in corodva - "cordova plugin rm nl.x-services.plugins.backgroundaudio" could you try removing double quote and check once?

Comment: @Gandhi Thanks for the response, I tried without quotes `phonegap plugin remove nl.x-services.plugins.backgroundaudio` but it does not work. For the above command it says `cordova: command not found`.

Comment: I tried out using Cordova CLI 6.1.1 in windows. Could you check out phonegap equivalent command for the same? In worst case, you can remove the plugin folder manually by deleting it and removing its corresponding entry from fetch.json inside plugins folder. You may also have to remove and re- add your platform once

Comment: @Gandhi No same issue :( I will try rebuilding the platform. Thanks again.